# Intrinsics for 128 multiplication and division

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly, intrinsics, 128-bit

In x86_64 I know that the mul and div opp codes support 128 integers by putting the lower 64 bits in the rax and the upper in the rdx registers.  I was looking for some sort of intrinsic to do this in the intel intrinsics guide and I could not find one.  I am writing a big number library where the word size is 64 bits.  Right now I am doing division by a single word like this.

```
int ubi_div_i64(ubigint_t* a, ubi_i64_t b, ubi_i64_t* rem)
{
    if(b == 0)
        return UBI_MATH_ERR;

    ubi_i64_t r = 0;

    for(size_t i = a->used; i-- > 0;)
    {

        ubi_i64_t out;
        __asm__("\t"
                "div %[d] \n\t"
                : "=a"(out), "=d"(r)
                : "a"(a->data[i]), "d"(r), [d]"r"(b)
                : "cc");
        a->data[i] = out;


        //ubi_i128_t top = (r << 64) + a->data[i];
        //r = top % b;
        //a->data[i] = top / b;
    }
    if(rem)
        *rem = r;

    return ubi_strip_leading_zeros(a);
}
```

It would be nice if I could use something in the x86intrinsics.h header instead of inline asm.

Comment: Since asm is already compiler specific, you might as well just use the `__int128` type which will automatically do what you want.

Comment: Take a look at _mulx_u64. Looks like a perfect fit for your use, although it generates the mulx instruction which is present only on newer x86 processors.

Comment: Given the choice between architecture specific intrinsics and architecture specific assembly; the latter is better documented, better supported, more widely understood and easier to maintain (no need to guess what the compiler actually did).

Answer (score 2):

gcc has `__int128` and `__uint128` types.

Arithmetic with them *should* be using the right assembly instructions when they exist; I've used them in the past to get the upper 64 bits of a product, although I've never used it for division. If it's not using the right ones, submit a bug report / feature request as appropriate.

Comment: I decompiled the code when I built it on -03.  I was surprised that gcc was calling a function instead of inlining one when using the 128 bit division. Just seemed kind of slow.

Comment: @chasep255 GCC doesn't use the "expanded" form of DIV/IDIV because it would be non-conforming. This is true both with 128-bit dividends on 64-bit x86 targets and 64-bit dividends on 32-bit x86 targets. The problem is that DIV will cause divide overflow exceptions in cases where the standard says the result should be truncated. For example `(unsigned long long) (((unsigned _int128) 1 << 64) / 1)` should evaluate to 0, but would cause divide overflow exception if evaluated with DIV.

Answer (score 1):

[Last I looked into it the intrinsic were in a state of flux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206981/intrinsic-for-the-mulx-instruction). The main reason for the intrinsics in this case appears to be due to the fact that MSVC in 64-bit mode does not allow inline assembly.

With MSVC (and I think ICC) you can use `_umul128` for `mul` and `_mulx_u64` for `mulx`. These don't work in GCC , at least not GCC 4.9 (`_umul128` is much older than GCC 4.9). I don't know if GCC plans to support these since you can get `mul` and `mulx` indirectly through `__int128` (depending on your compile options) or directly through inline assembly.

`__int128` works fine until you need a larger type and a 128-bit carry. Then you need `adc`, `adcx`, or `adox` and these are even more of a problem with intrinsics. Intel's documentation disagree's with MSVC and the compilers don't seem to produce `adox` yet with these intrinsics. See this question: [_addcarry_u64 and _addcarryx_u64 with MSVC and ICC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229371/addcarry-u64-and-addcarryx-u64-with-msvc-and-icc).

Inline assembly is probably the best solution with GCC (and probably even ICC).