# Emit DIV instruction, instead of __udivti3

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, clang, x86-64

Consider the following code:

```
unsigned long long div(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b, unsigned long long c) {
    unsigned __int128 d = (unsigned __int128)a*(unsigned __int128)b;
    return d/c;
}
```

When compiled with x86-64 gcc 10 or clang 10, both with `-O3`, it [emits](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/yLRzK_) `__udivti3`, instead of `DIVQ` instruction:

```
div:
    mov     rax, rdi
    mov     r8, rdx
    sub     rsp, 8
    xor     ecx, ecx
    mul     rsi
    mov     r9, rax
    mov     rsi, rdx
    mov     rdx, r8
    mov     rdi, r9
    call    __udivti3
    add     rsp, 8
    ret
```

At least in my testing, the former is much slower than the (already) slow later, hence the question: is there a way to make a modern compiler emit `DIVQ` for the above code?

Edit: Let's assume the quotient fits into 64-bits register.

Comment: Did you compile with `-march=native`?

Comment: @Ctx Yes, still emitting `__udivti3`, for both `-march=native` or `-march=skylake`.

Comment: IMO 128bit support is very limited

Comment: 128 bit /64 bit divq is only fast enough since Ice Lake...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`div` will fault if the quotient doesn't fit in 64 bits.  Doing `(a*b) / c` with mul + a single div isn't safe in the general case (doesn't implement the abstract-machine semantics for every possible input), therefore a compiler can't generate asm that way for x86-64.

Even if you do give the compiler enough info to figure out that the division can't overflow (i.e. that `high_half < divisor`), unfortunately gcc/clang still won't ever optimize it to single a [`div`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div) with a non-zero high-half dividend (RDX).

You need an intrinsic or inline asm to explicitly do 128 / 64-bit => 64-bit division.  e.g. [Intrinsics for 128 multiplication and division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540740/intrinsics-for-128-multiplication-and-division) has GNU C inline asm that looks right for low/high halves separately.

Unfortunately GNU C doesn't have an intrinsic for this.  MSVC does, though: [Unsigned 128-bit division on 64-bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870158/unsigned-128-bit-division-on-64-bit-machine/60013652#60013652) has links.

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in the case when it cannot overflow, I even tried `unsigned __int128 d = (unsigned __int128)(a%c)*(unsigned __int128)(b%c)` which is even worse. What do you mean by `with a non-zero RDX`? That if the division is exact (i.e. no remainder), it will emit `DIVQ`?

Comment: @EcirHana: I mean a non-zero high-half *input* to division.  [`div`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div) takes its dividend input in RDX:RAX.

Comment: Ah, ok. `DX` also contains the remainder after the division, so I was not sure.

Comment: @EcirHana: strictly, `DIVQ xx` will overflow if `RDX >= xx`, because the quotient is then 2^64 or more.  But for all divisors (other than `0`) `RDX == 0`  is OK.  I tried adding `if ((d >> 64) >= c) return ULLONG_MAX ;` and `if ((d >> 64) != 0) return ULLONG_MAX ;` in front of the `return d/c ;`: the compiler was clever enough to test `RDX` in both cases, but still no `DIVQ` (with gcc 10.1 and clang 10.0.0) :-(.