# Replace gcc asm function with __uint128_t equivalent

Tags: c++, c, assembly, gcc, clang

I have a few utilities that promote 128 bit operations like 64x64 bit multiplications that I have successfully translated to the equivalent __uint128_t arithmetic with carry. I checked and gcc generates exactly the same assembly instructions.

However I am failing to find the equivalent C/C++ code for the case of 128-bit division. The original asm statement is this:

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
void div64(uint64_t low, uint64_t high, uint64_t divisor,
                         uint64_t& quotient, uint64_t& remainder) {
    asm("divq %2" : "+a"(low), "+d"(high) : "rm"(divisor));
    quotient = low;
    remainder = high;
}
```

However when I try to replace it with this

```cpp
void div64( uint64_t low, uint64_t high, uint64_t divisor,
            uint64_t& quotient, uint64_t& remainder) {
    __uint128_t val = __uint128_t(low) | (__uint128_t(high)<<64);
    quotient = val/divisor;
    remainder = val%divisor;
}
```

The compiler fails to match these operations to a single `divq` instruction. Instead, it produces a much longer version with an additional library call to __udivti3, even in `-O3` optimization mode.

[Godbolt Link](https://godbolt.org/z/h4K9rhjxW)

```cpp
div64b(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long&, unsigned long&):                       # @div64b(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long&, unsigned long&)
        pushq   %r15
        pushq   %r14
        pushq   %r12
        pushq   %rbx
        pushq   %rax
        movq    %r8, %r14
        movq    %rcx, %r15
        movq    %rdx, %r12
        movq    %rdi, %rbx
        xorl    %ecx, %ecx
        callq   __udivti3@PLT
        movq    %rax, (%r15)
        imulq   %r12, %rax
        subq    %rax, %rbx
        movq    %rbx, (%r14)
        addq    $8, %rsp
        popq    %rbx
        popq    %r12
        popq    %r14
        popq    %r15
        retq
```

Am I missing anything?

Note: I tagged this question with both `C` and `C++` because the code above is valid on both languages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62257103/emit-div-instruction-instead-of-udivti3

Comment: Even if GCC could prove that the quotient will fit in a uint64_t (and thus not `#DE` -> SIGFPE), it misses the optimization.  (i.e. that `high < divisor`).  In your case it's not even possible since the pure C has to safely truncate the result, not raise an exception.  e.g. try your inline asm with `0x10000:0000000000000000 / 1` or something.

Comment: @user253751  I do not think it answers the question as I still believe there would be a way to rewrite that code without an asm statement such that the compiler will generate an optimized function.

Comment: @PeterCordes it would be up to the precondition. Every C/C++ function has a set of preconditions that would crash it if violated.

Comment: Ok, then that makes your inline asm function safe to use *in your program*.  But clearly, even if GCC were smarter, it couldn't optimize a stand-alone version of this function that way, because the pure C version has well-defined behaviour for some inputs where a single div would fault. It *could* after inlining, if the pre-condition were something it could prove at compile time.  But unfortunately even with a guarantee like that, it won't do the optimization (unless something has changed.)